# Lossless steering Order of Magnitude estimation

Tags: information-theory, quantum-mechanics, filters

This is an equation from Rau's book "Quantum theory-an Information Processing Approach". It's leading to "lossless steering" of a particle if you insert an infinite number of filters between the initial state and the last filter and for the last step you have to substitute x for $2^n+1$ (n: number of filters) an then let $n\to\infty$. I am a little bit lost because I don't know to handle the $O(f(x))^x$ expression and arrive at the right hand side for $x\to\infty$. Any suggestions on what to read up on, or hints for a solution? Thanks.
$$(1 - O(1/x^2)) ^ x \approx  1 - O(1/x)$$

Comment: You should use MathJax formatting not only for the equation, but for any formulae, unknowns names, and so on. For example, it’s better to type `$2^n+1$`

Comment: Ok, sorry, used it for the first time and got some formatting problems, inline didn't work somehow...

Comment: You don’t have to use HTML, or XML, or full format LaTeX, or nothing like that on this site. You just type (or copy paste) plain text. And then put $ signs around your formulae. [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) is that simple. Well, you also type \to instead of -> and \infty instead of the Unicode symbol.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the heads up.